# Decoding Bluetooth HCI log for Cycling Trainer

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, android-bluetooth

trying to figure out how to control the trainer. got this bluetooth HCI logs but unsure if there's a Method to "unlock" the trainer before sending the command.

This is the sequence which I'm seeing from the Manufacturer's App sent to the trainer.

I don't quite understand this particular output. It looks to me that this Char UUID has the `Indication` characteristic. Is the app actually sending anything to the trainer? I don't see a `Value` being written. (Is it correct to presume that all writes will have a `Value` Hex?)

[image]

This is sending 100w (6400 or 0064 in LSB) target power to the trainer.
[image]

This is sending 300w (2c01 or 012c in LSB) target power to the trainer.
[image]

Here are the 2 btsnoop logs from 2 different apps if anyone is willing/wants to look further.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/86wox4ywz3sjr2v/btsnoop_hci%28TrainerRoad%29.log?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pgs6j4fg6opjrij/btsnoop_hci1%28Saris%29.log?dl=0

Comment: A next step might be to use a generic Bluetooth Low Energy scanning and exploration tool like [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) to experiment with sending data/commands and getting notifications back.

Comment: Is the first image above showing Indications being enabled? This normally happens after the client connects.

Comment: @ukBaz I wish that it was as simple as that. (This is not my trainer so I have no access to it). with regards to the 2nd comment, I don't really know. is this how a  ```peripheral.setIndicate(true)``` would look like?

Comment: Not so familiar with Android development and I have no way of testing but it seems like it might be a [setCharacteristicNotification](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt#setCharacteristicNotification(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic,%20boolean)

Comment: same here, I got the logs from someone else and hoping someone here can decipher it w/ more details. Thanks tho